# How do I create an Ec2 Instance with a Public IP automatically **without** declaring an Elastic IP in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In AWS Cloudformation, is there any way to declare an EC2 instance in VPC with a Public IP **without** the need to declare an Elastic IP and attach to it?

In AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration, you could add a property "AssociatePublicIpAddress" to say the instances will accept a Public IP automatically. I am looking for the equivalent for AWS::EC2::Instance

Below is my cloudformation snippet for creating an EC2 instance. I can't any doc that mentions how to add a public IP without having to declare an Elastic IP beforehand.

```
"MyEc2Instance": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties": {
        "IamInstanceProfile": {
            "Ref": "MyEc2InstanceProfile"
        },
        "ImageId": {
            "Fn::FindInMap": [
                "MyEc2Box",
                {
                    "Ref": "Region"
                },
                "ImageId"
            ]
        },
        "InstanceType": {
            "Fn::FindInMap": [
                "MyEc2Box",
                {
                    "Ref": "Region"
                },
                "InstanceType"
            ]
        },
        "KeyName": {
            "Ref": "DefaultKeyPair"
        },
        "Monitoring": "true",
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
            {
                "Ref": "MyEc2SecurityGroup"
            }
        ],
        "SubnetId": {
            "Ref": "MyBoxSubnet"
        },
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "MyBox"
            },
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: Public IP is assigned automatically when create ec2 instance. You needn't manually add it. Do you require to add send public IP?

Comment: There's a setting in the subnet settings: "Auto-assign Public IP" have you tried that?

Comment: Should my answer be the correct one, can you mark it as such to help other to sort out valid answers ?  thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming you are starting your instance in a VPC public subnet (i.e. a subnet that has a routing table incl. a rule to send traffic to 0.0.0.0/0 to the Internet Gateway), just define AssociatePublicIpAddress property in the NetworkInterfaces group of your EC2 resource:

```
            "NetworkInterfaces" : [{
                 "AssociatePublicIpAddress" : "True",
                 "DeleteOnTermination" : "True",
                 "SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet" },
                 "DeviceIndex" : "0",
                 "GroupSet" : [ { "Ref" : "SecurityGroup" } ]
            }],
```

See documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html

If you are starting your instance in EC2 Classic networking (non VPC), it will receive a public IP address automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to configure it in the Subnet, so all EC2 instances get a public IP by default? Equivalent to checking "Auto-assign Public IP" option in the subnet configuration, available in AWS console UI.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.  The API to change this value is ModifySubnetAttribute (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifySubnetAttribute.html) and must be called on an existing subnet.  I can not find an equivalent in CloudFormation but I would love to be proven wrong on this point :-)

Comment: This does not make sense if you have multiple subnets the instance may be launched into (for example as part of auto-scaling and load balancing). There should be (is there maybe?) a setting to simply auto assign a public IP to the instance, without specifying a network interface?

Comment: If you do use this method, make sure you don't have a SubnetId or SecurityGroups property defined outside of your NetworkInterfaces property otherwise you will throw an error like: "Network interfaces and an instance-level security groups may not be specified on the same request"

Answer (score 7):

I see that this is an old post but i post the answer anyway it can be helpful. 
In the subnet you can set : "MapPublicIpOnLaunch" to True so all the instance of this subnet will have a public IP.

```
MapPublicIpOnLaunch

Indicates whether instances that are launched in this subnet receive a public IP address. By default, the value is false.

Required: No

Type: Boolean

Update requires: No interruption.
```

Comment: Although it does indeed set the default for the subnet public IP to true (which, literally, was part of the question), it seems that CloudFormation-started instances don't adhere to this setting, so it's not useful for starting a CF instance with a public ip